# AVR Atmega32a USART library isn't working

Tags: avr, atmega, usart

```c
/*
 * RC_Car_AVR.c
 *
 * Created: 4/18/2018 7:55:07 PM
 * Author : 
 */ 

#define F_CPU 16000000
#define BAUD 9600
#define TUBRR (((F_CPU / 16) / BAUD) - 1)

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

char Read;

void USART_Init(void){
    
    UBRRL = TUBRR;
    
    UCSRB = (1<<TXEN)|(1<<RXEN);
    UCSRC = (1<<UCSZ1)|(1<<UCSZ0);
}

char USART_Receive(void){
    
    /* Wait for data to be received */
    while (!(UCSRA & (1<<RXC)));
    
    /* Get and return received data from buffer */
    return UDR;
}

int main(void){
    
    USART_Init();
    
    DDRB |= (1<<0);
    
    PORTB |= (1<<0); 
    
    while (1){
        
        Read = USART_Receive();
        
        if(Read == 'F'){
            
            PORTB ^= (1<<0);
            _delay_ms(100);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to toggle an LED when I receive a certain character through the Bluetooth module (HC05).

I've written the USART library just like the datasheet but it doesn't seem to work (I'm only concerned with the initialization and receiving code since I'm working on a half duplex system so i don't need the transmition part).

I'm using Atmega32a with a 16MHz external crystal Oscillator.

Please tell me if you find anything wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Code looks OK at a quick glance. You will have to narrow the issue down. Is the BT module actually receiving/working? Is the HW interface compatible (3.3V/5V UART or even RS232?) Is the frame format and BAUD matching? is the controller really running at 16MHz  or maybe internal clock (Fuse settings)? And so on.

Comment: the bluetooth module is always recieving 255 (11111111) for some reason so i interfaced it with an 18F4620 PIC Microcontroller and it worked just fine. The hardware is compatible no problem with that & i've configured the fuse bits for a 16 MHz external crystal. Could you please elaborate the Frame & Baud matching?
Thank You.

Comment: I just meant to check, that the BT module and the Controller use the same BAUD rate (is the BT module sending @9600?). Additionally there are different frame options with respect to data bits, parity and stopbits. Those have to be identical as well. However, most likely the common format of 8 data, 1 stop and no parity is used anyway. But double check it.

Comment: Shouldn't it be  `UCSRC = (1<<URSEL)|(1<<UCSZ1)|(1<<UCSZ0);`? Otherwise it will be written to the `UBRRH`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Initialization is wrong.

Try this

```
void USART_Init(void){

UBRRL = TUBRR;
UBRRH = TUBRR >> 8;
UCSRB = (1<<TXEN)|(1<<RXEN);
UCSRC = (1<<UCSZ1)|(3<<UCSZ0);


}
```

This is the following initialization code provided in data sheet of atmega32

```
void USART_Init( unsigned int baud )
{
    /* Set baud rate */
    UBRRH = (unsigned char)(baud>>8);
    UBRRL = (unsigned char)baud;
    /* Enable receiver and transmitter */
    UCSRB = (1<<RXEN)|(1<<TXEN);
    /* Set frame format: 8data, 2stop bit */
    UCSRC = (1<<URSEL)|(1<<USBS)|(3<<UCSZ0);
}
```

I know following datasheet is little overhead in beginning But eventually you will see all your answers are provided there.